# What does the following re code mean?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I don't understand this code in Python. I know what the function does but I don't get how and what those `\\` do in the replacement string.

```
import re
caps="([A-Z])"
pre="(Mr|mr|Mr|St|st|ST|Mrs|MRS|mrs|Ms|MS|ms|Dr|DR|dr|miss|Miss|MISS)[\.\.\.]"
def tokenize_sentence(text):
    text=re.sub(" ?"+pre,"\\1<dot>",text)
    text = re.sub(caps + "[.]" + caps + "[.]" + caps + "[.]", "\\1<prd>\\2<prd>\\3<prd>", text)
    print(text)
tokenize_sentence("Mr. Ansh sahajpal A.B.C.")
```

The output is:

```
Mr<dot> Ansh sahajpal A<prd>B<prd>C<prd>
```

If you can explain me how does the `\\1`, `\\2` and `\\3` does in the `sub` functions it will be amazing. Also I changed the input to `Mr... Ansh sahajpal` and in the line 5 I made the following change:

```
text=re.sub(" ?"+pre,"\\1<dot>\\2<dot>",text)
```

What I thought it will do is replace the first `.` and the second `.` but it gave me an error.
Please any explanation will do.

Comment: Your question is off topic since you are asking for debugging help. If you run a debugger line by line you can understand what your code does. Btw, `\1` or `\someNumber` is the regex capturing group index, so if your regex captured `hello` then if you use `\1` you are referencing to hello, so `\1\1` will be `hellohello`

Comment: Note that Python, of all languages, is very sensitive to indentation.  What you wrote wouldn't compile because you'd not indented the body of the function.  I've guessed the scope of the function.  Please be very careful next time.   Also, when you report "it gave me an error", please quote verbatim the error message you received.  I assume it said something about there not being a second captured string for the `\\2` to refer to — but we shouldn't have to guess; you should tell us from the start.

Answer (score 3):

The `\1`, `\2`, etc refer to matched subexpressions (enclosed in parentheses) in a regular expression.   `\1` is the first expression matched, `\2` is the second, etc.  They are used in the replacement string to mark where matched subexpressions are to be modified.

Common convention for matching subexpressions is to use parenthesis.  Here is an example:

```
str = 'an example word:cat!!'
print (re.sub (r'word:(\w+)', r'\0dog', str))
```

which says match any number of alphanumeric characters following a colon and yields:

```
an example word:dog!!
```

In this case, (\w+) is a grouped expression for the set of alphanumeric characters including "_".